# How Expensive Is This jQuery Trigger?

Tags: jquery, triggers

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/BYETL/3/) demonstrates what I'm talking about. Essentially, I'm binding some elements to a custom event and then calling a trigger using

```
$('*').trigger('myevent', args)
```

I'm doing this because I will have some elements bound to this event, but I don't know what they will be yet, and I'd like to decouple this code as much as possible. Is it ridiculously expensive to call `$('*').trigger` or not that expensive since it will only trigger the elements that are bound to that event?

In other words, does this code go through every element on the page to see if it is attached to this event, or does it know which ones are and just triggers them? If the former is the case, is there a better solution?

Comment: jQuery creates a list of all nodes matching the selector, then tells them all to trigger the event. What do you mean by "`I don't know what they will be yet`"?

Comment: @kevin i mean that this code is part of a control that will be inserted into various pages that i want to bind to events, but i don't know what elements on that page are going to be bound. i want to create a generic solution that has a few triggers to be hooked into

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug to profile this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of pubsub? Something as simple as.

```
(function() {
    var $obj = $(window);

    window.pub = function(ev, data) {
        $obj.trigger(ev, data);
    };

    window.sub = function(ev, f) {
        $obj.bind(ev, f);
    };
})();
```

or drop the jQuery dependency

```
(function() {
    var $obj = {},
        undefined;

    window.pub = function(ev, data) {
        if ($obj[ev] === undefined) {
            return false;
        }
        for (var i = 0, len = $obj[ev].length; i < len; i++) {
            $obj[ev][i](data);
        }
    };

    window.sub = function(ev, f) {
        if ($obj[ev] === undefined) {
            $obj[ev] = [];
        }
        $obj[ev].push(f);
    };
})();
```

Both [amplify.subscribe](http://amplifyjs.com/api/pubsub/) and [Backbone.Events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events) have specific objects for this. You may even find other libraries with similar objects. There are even libraries [PubSub.js](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) for this.

Example:

```
$("table.sort th").click(function(e) {
    ...
    window.pub("click.sortHeader", e); 
});

...

$.fn.pagify = function(json) {
    var table = $(this);
    ...
    //enter code here

    window.sub("click.sortHeader", function() {
         // handle table sorting.

         // adjust table pagifying plugin accordingly.
    });
};
```

In general `pub` is `trigger` and `sub` is `bind`. In this particular example we have two independent plugins. They don't know whether they are on the same page or talking at all. But since the sorting "breaks" the paging plugin on our table we have a subscription on the sorting "event" to fix our paging.

Someone else can come up with a better example. It's basically just a way of message passing without making any assumptions about whether either the message giver or receiver exists.

Comment: i've never heard of pubsub... how does this work? i'm looking at this and have no idea what this is supposed to do

Comment: ok i did some research on pubsub and i think it's exactly what i want. basically a way for the sender and receiver to be completely unaware of the other. how would the above code work in practice?

Comment: @Jason small example attached.

Comment: thanks, raynos. this is perfect and exactly what i was looking for. now i can have my objects publish things to whatever wants to hook into them. awesome!

Answer (score 6):

The better solution is to bind and trigger events off of the document, since it will only be one DOM element:

```
$(document).bind('myevent', function(e) {});

$(document).trigger('myevent');
```

Now ultimately what sounds like an even better solution to your problem would be to use event delegation:

```
$(document).delegate('.my-delegation-selector', 'myevent', function(e) {

});
```

Take a look at this example from http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  p { color:red; }
  span { color:blue; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Has an attached custom event.</p>
  <button>Trigger custom event</button>
  <span style="display:none;"></span>
<script>

    $("body").delegate("p", "myCustomEvent", function(e, myName, myValue){
      $(this).text("Hi there!");
      $("span").stop().css("opacity", 1)
               .text("myName = " + myName)
               .fadeIn(30).fadeOut(1000);
    });
    $("button").click(function () {
      $("p").trigger("myCustomEvent");
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: or `window` as its not a DOM element and is only 6 characters instead of 8!.

Comment: @eli, the point is, i won't know what elements will be attached to the trigger. i can't just say `$(#someelement, #otherelement, #etc).trigger()`. i need something generic that will just fire the event and anything attached to that event will fire

Comment: +1 for solving his actual problem. @Jason `.live` is evil and expensive. .trigger is cheap.

Comment: @raynos `.live` is evil? howso?

Comment: @Jason EVIL! search delegate vs live on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at jquery source code. When you trigger an event on jQuery it check for a valid node

```
    // don't do events on text and comment nodes
    if ( !elem || elem.nodeType === 3 || elem.nodeType === 8 ) {
        return undefined;
    }
```

And later check for a valid handler on the actual dom object

```
    // Trigger the event, it is assumed that "handle" is a function
    var handle = jQuery._data( elem, "handle" );

    if ( handle ) {
        handle.apply( elem, data );
    }
```

I think that the real problem is the use of $('*') selector. Try another of the suggested solutions to your problem

Comment: so what you're saying is that it _is_ expensive to do `$('*').trigger()`?

Comment: @Jason: I say that the expensive operation comes from selecting all the nodes $('*') and not for triggering the event on each one because not all the nodes have a handler attached to them